# Log4js not write into the file from the catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

I want to log errors on try catch construct using log4js. I have next code:

```
let log4js = require('log4js')
log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    asterisk: {type: 'file', filename: 'filename'},
    out: {type: 'stdout'},
  },
  categories: {default: {appenders: ['asterisk', 'out'], level: 'all'}}
})
const logger = log4js.getLogger('asterisk')
async function myFunc() {
  try {
    let tmp = await someFunc()
  }
  catch (err) {
    logger.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}
myFunc()
```

When an error occurs, I see it in the console, but it is not written to the file. If I use logger outside try..catch block then everything works fine.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested to me on GitHub, the problem is in the process.exit - this causes node to exit before the logger.error call (which is asynchronous behind the scenes) has written to the file.
Right code will be like this:

```
logger.error(err)
logger.shutdown(() => process.exit(1))
```

and it works fine.